# How do I display a message similar to Window.alert() in OfficeJS

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to display a custom message, but `window.alert()` is restricted in OfficeJS.

I have found a solution which suggests using `app.showNotification(title, message);`

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
             app.showNotification("Title For the Notification", "test");
    });
 });
```

Browser throws

> "app is undefined error".

Which module am I missing ?

Comment: You grab 3 lines of code from context of [Office Add-in Dialog API Example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/tree/master/SimpleDialogSampleWeb) which uses `FabricUI` package to display alert style dialog (basically layer on the current page). Bottom line: `app` is the application someone defined in the code you didn't copy; `showNotification` is custom defined function someone implemented. Nothing to do with OfficeJS.

Comment: I see, thank you for pointing that out. It's clear for me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer on original question (in your title) you may use [Fabric-UI Dialog API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/dialog/dialog) to achive this functionality. The examples of the options for available dialog's styles [over here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/ghdocs/components/Dialog.md). You may use any other UI package as well ... JQuery UI, JQuery Mobile, etc.

Comment: I will try to use JQuery UI because I'm trying to avoid Dialog API alltogether

Comment: Office dialog is best from third-party library

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the Fabric dialog as Slava suggested, you can also use the Dialog API in Office.js. There's a discussion of it here: [Use the Dialog API in your Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am currently using the Dialog API which I totally dislike because it does generate errors on Outlook Windows. I wanted to avoid it at all cost.